# Remove generated category and tag class names from woocommerce product & blog listings markup

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I noticed in my wordpress/woocommerce setup that every time i add a tag to a product or a blog post. It adds that tag as a class into the listed item (Product/blog)

I also noticed it adds a class in the same place for every category i put these post items into.

How can i prevent wordpress and woocommerce from addings these tag and category names into my html markup as classes? As i do not need them and its creating a mess.

Thanks for any help! I could not locate a similar function anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to leverage the woocommerce [`wc_product_post_class`](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/functions/wc_product_post_class/) filter. The following code should do the trick.

```php
function my_strip_tag_class( $classes ) {

    global $post;
    $product_tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );

    if( $product_tags ) foreach ( $product_tags as $tag ) {

        $tag_index = array_search($tag, $classes);

          if($tag_index !== false){
            unset($classes[$tag_index]);
        }

    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'wc_product_post_class', 'my_strip_tag_class' );
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. When trying to apply your code to my functions.php file i get this error "Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 638 of file wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Cannot redeclare wc_get_product_class() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/child-theme/functions.php:839)"

Comment: Sorry, I made a terrible mistake in my answer, I will edit it

Comment: Please let me know once you are done editing it.

Comment: @KYSSE take a look now

Answer (score 0):

For WooCommerce 3.6.2+ try the `woocommerce_post_class` filter:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_post_class', function($classes, $product) {
    // remove whatever classes you want here...
    return $classes;
}, 10, 2);
```